# merge data.frame different length and condition by two columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge 2 data.frame with different length. In the positions with no identical values of the columns that refer to coordinates (longitude and latitude) I wanted NA. I'm using merge but the result is not correct and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. There should be NA (or I expected) in the columns where the second data frame don't have same coordinates and leave the values when the coordinates (columns lon and lat) in both data.frames are the same.
These are a short sample of my original data looks like:

# d1

```
               lon lat   MDA8O3
               -17.0  32 79.32538
               -16.6  32 79.36805
               -16.2  32 79.36243
               -15.8  32 79.36818
               -15.4  32 79.36213
               -15.0  32 79.34682
# d2
                  O3  lon   lat
            91.09123 13.8 48.50
            93.46220 16.6 47.75
            90.93342 15.8 48.75
            93.77436 13.0 46.75
            38.84968 11.8 47.25
            93.88587 14.6 47.75
```

Now, I using:
         df <- merge(d1,d2, by=c("lon","lat"),all.x=T)

But, the results is not correct:

```
             lon lat   MDA8O3       O3
             -17  32 79.32538 25.10291
             -17  32 79.32538 52.06498
             -17  32 79.32538 73.24021
             -17  32 79.32538 31.79225
             -17  32 79.32538 20.99357
             -17  32 79.32538 24.55819
```

I also try, with all=T and it's not correct. In the column O3 should be NA in those lon and lat that don't match the lon and lat of the first data.frame.

What am I doing wrong? I thought merge could be used here, any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use `left_join()` function from `dplyr` package. It should do what you're looking for and works the same way than `merge` (and is also more efficient).

Comment: I can't replicate your results table.  When I run the exact same code (with all.x = T), I get all NAs in the O3 column as you'd expect.

Comment: I get all `NA` for `O3` when I do the merge.  My guess: you've assigned a variable named `T`.  Always use `TRUE` and `FALSE` for logicals.  Try `merge(d1, d2, by = c("lon", "lat"), all.x = TRUE)`.

Comment: Yes, it seemed odd that all the numbers in the O3 column don't exist in either d1 or d2.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the different length of arrays? I'm doing the same only with the short samples that I put here as an example (which is the head of each original data) and I got NA, as you did. But if I use the original data, I don't get NA..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`left_join()` function from `dplyr` package should work.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(lon = c(-17, -16.6, -16.2, -15.8, -15.4, -15),
                   lat = rep(32, 6),
                   MDA8o3 = c(79.32538, 79.36805, 79.36243, 79.36818, 79.36213, 79.34682))

dat2 <- data.frame(lon = c(13.8, 16.6, 15.8, 13.0, 11.8, 14.6),
                   lat = c(48.50, 47.75, 48.75, 46.75, 47.25, 47.75),
                   o3 = c(91.09123, 93.46220, 90.93342, 93.77436, 38.84968, 93.88587))


library(dplyr)

res <- left_join(dat1, dat2, by = c("lon", "lat"))
```

Comment: I got similar results with left_join :(

Comment: Could you add some matching lines in your examples? It seems that there is no common lon/lat combination between your 2 data.frames.